# How to break this loop?

Tags: c++

I have this code to average 100 pictures and save them into 10 JPEG files

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    VideoCapture cap("C:/Pics/test_%d.jpeg");
    while (cap.isOpened())
    {
        Mat img;
        cap.read(img);
        // process(img);
        if (img.empty()) break;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar());
            for (int avgnumb = 10 * i; avgnumb < (10 * i) +10; ++avgnumb)
            {
                cv::accumulate(img, avgImg);
            }
            avgImg = avgImg / 10;
            avgImg.convertTo(avgImg, CV_8UC3);
            char filename[100];
            sprintf(filename, "C:/AvgPics/test_%d.jpeg", i);
            imwrite(filename, avgImg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, even after finishing saving the 9th file, it doesn't break and continue to overwrite the saved file again and again. Can anyone help me in this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove the `while`

Comment: You have 2 loops.  You forgot about the `while`?

Comment: Why do you have a format-string for the `VideoCapture` object constructor? What will the argument to that `"%d"` be? Where do you set it?

Comment: Without knowing what these library functions do, no.....

Comment: Omg, caffeine has ruined my brain....

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Just remove the `while`

Comment: That's the correct answer! I... I mean the second part of course.